# Starting binary input with 0s in a cell

Tags: excel, binary

First up, I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this or not, so if it's not please let me know.

Ok so,I'm working on a project that deals with numbers in the binary format as inputs, however, when the input let's say begins with "00" or any number of 0s, it discards it in Excel so I was wondering how to force excel to accept 0s at the beginning of a binary input

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the simplest solution after working with Excel this past week.

To include leading 0s, I should select the cell containing my decimal number and simply use the dec2bin function in Excel and define how many bits I want to output to be.

=DEC2BIN([number or cell reference],[#bits])

So if you enter "=DEC2BIN(A1,8)" in the formula bar, and the value of A1 is 15, the value output will be 00001111.

Answer (score 4):

You need to provide it with a custom format!

Select the cell(s), and go to the Format Cells dialog (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>1</kbd>). In the number format, choose Category "Custom" and here enter `0000` as the custom format. The number of 0 indicate the total number of digits display. If less are entered, it'll be filled with leading 0.

[image]

Comment: @Sara or use the format "**Text**" it will preserve your original string containing binary digits as-is. You can learn more about custom formats at http://jonvonderheyden.net/excel/a-comprehensive-guide-to-number-formats-in-excel and
http://www.yogeshguptaonline.com/2009/10/excel-number-format-indian-style-comma.html Nice example of using "binary numbers" in Excel for OR,XOR,AND,NOT is at http://chandoo.org/wp/2011/07/29/bitwise-operations-in-excel/#comment-207723

Comment: What this will do is to 1) remove any leading zero and store it as the normal number (e.g. `00101` will become `101`) - and 2) format it with the custom format, adding leading zeros if the number of digits is not sufficient. In the example, the `101` would become `0101` if you'd use `0000` as format - or `00101` with the format `00000`. HTH

Answer (score 1):

An old post, still:

I was having the same issue (with IP numbers) and found a different solution:

In one cell you do the conversion: =DE2BIN(10)

In the other cell you format it with TEXT formula: =TEXT($A$1,"00000000").